# How do I extract specific column from a function values?

Tags: python, function

So, I have a categorical data frame. I have to extract the unique values of all the columns in the df.

Say:

```
A B C

a c b 

b c t

a d h

a d b
```

Here's my code:

```py
def A():

    def count_unique(data_final):

        return data_final.nunique(dropna=False)

    print(count_unique(data_final))

A()
```

Yes,I got it through this. The result looks like this

```
A 2

B 2

C 3
```

Now, I want to extract only the 2nd column i.e,[2,2,3] as a list. which will help me to use
`column1=col_name.repeat().`

---

- Where I get an error,
  object too deep for the desired array
  why is that?
- How do I extract the 2nd column and convert it as a list?

---

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it

```
def count_unique(data_final):
    return data_final.nunique(dropna=False).values.tolist()
```

Comment: Thanks !! it worked :).. How do I assign a variable name to that list . So, that i can use it in the later stages.

Comment: Now . if I want to extract the 1st column .i.e, [A,B,C] . What do I do??